# Java - Handling localized fields for Objects

Tags: java, object

I have several objects - of Class A that are imported using Json.  Each have 2 fields.

```
Several Objects (of Class A)
  - field-1
  - field-2
```

In the program - the values of the fields are changed.  These objects are then returned with the updated fields.

Within the program - we need to "create and keep track" of few "Temporary" fields for each of these objects - example

```
Several Objects (of Class A)
  - field-1
  - field-2
  - Temp-field-3
  - Temp-field-4
```

After the run.  The Objects are sent back- with the original field (i.e. field-1 and field-2).

Class A - is being used by several programs, thus we cannot add the "Temp" fields to the Class definition itself.

Right now - I map the Objects of Class-A (2 fields), to Objects of Class-B (which has the 4 fields - including temp fields; local to the program). At the end of the run - the Objects of Class-A are updated with the field values from corresponding Objects from Class-B.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: sub-classing seems cleaner, that way you always will have Class A which can be used as-is. Or Decorator pattern, may be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can avoid mapping from A to B (and B to A) by using transient or JsonIgnore as illustrated below.

Below working sample explains it. It accounts of single object but you can extend it for List of object easily.

This way you still control the extended class but performance wise its not putting any overhead. And your serializing code is free from any changes in class A - for example a new field added.

Assuming that your class A has below fields.

```
class A {
    String name;
    String id;
    public String getName() {return name;}
    public void setName(String name) {this.name = name;}
    public String getId() {return id;}
    public void setId(String id) {this.id = id;}
}
```

Define class B as below

```
class B extends A {
    @JsonIgnore
    transient String temp_1;
    @JsonIgnore
    transient String temp_2;
    //Getter and setters
    public String getTemp_1() {return temp_1;}
    public void setTemp_1(String temp_1) {this.temp_1 = temp_1;}
    public String getTemp_2() {return temp_2;}
    public void setTemp_2(String temp_2) {this.temp_2 = temp_2;}
}
```

Sample code - **Note that it is directly deserializing to object B and not A.**

```
import java.io.IOException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

public class Sample {

    public B fromJson(String jsonA) throws Exception {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        return mapper.readValue(jsonA, B.class);
    }

    public void doProcess(B b){
        b.setTemp_1("newTemp1");
        b.setName("newName");
    }
    public String toJson(B b) throws JsonProcessingException{
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        return mapper.writeValueAsString(b);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) 
       throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException {

        String incomingJson = "{ \"id\": \"123\",  \"name\" : \"JM\" }";
        System.out.println("Input->  " + incomingJson);
        Sample sample = new Sample();
        B b = sample.fromJson(incomingJson);
        sample.doProcess(b);
        String modifiedJson = sample.toJson(b);
        System.out.println("Output-> "+modifiedJson);
    }
}
```

Output

```
Input->  { "id": "123",  "name" : "JM" }
Output-> {"name":"newName","id":"123"}
```

Comment: I used Jackon but you can use Gson or any other json serializer with transient marker and it will be ignored in from/to conversion.

Comment: Thanks @Jags.  Excellent example.  This will work for me.  Thanks.  A question... do you have to specify (at)JsonIgnore or defining them as transient makes it obvious for (I am using) Gson to ignore while creating the toJson string.

Comment: @userDSSR  Gson works well with just transient. No need to provide JsonIgnore.     If you are using Jackson then i believe 2.6.x+ versions works with just transient. Below that you will need to provide JsonIgnore

Answer (score 1):

[Json](http://www.json.org/) `is a lightweight data-interchange format.`, thus there is no variable definition, or ways to process data within it.

What you describe is that you want to read an initial value, then alter it, then save them... Those changes seem fit to be done inside the program, and then store the output as needed. The way this can be performed is heavily dependant on what your need is.

If all you have is a single machine performing all needed operations, then having `Class A JSON` holding both fields, then performing all operations, then outputting them as `Class A JSON` again, without the `Class B JSON`.

However, if the inbetween files are important, then having the `Class B JSON` is a good approach.

If you can, please state what conditions best fit your need. Otherwise, we can only guess what you want, and thus show our opinions about it.

Comment: It is a web application.  The Class-A definition is being shared by 4 such mini apps that share the contents of the Objects of Class-A and are responsible for sections (certain fields) of the Object.  The inbetween (temp) fields are not important and only used to derive the values for the main fields.

Comment: @userDSSR Ok, but how is the application executed? Are all of them in the same machine (and thus can share the same file), or are them run in 2+ different machines, and thus must be syncronized at some point? Finally, what is the scale of your files? are those 10 bits single Json files, or are they 10 GB files, and how many jsons are expected to exist/execute at once? 10 files? 1 million?

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply.  Each of the apps are run in a sequence - thus no synchronization needed.  They are running in the same machine.  The Jsons are usually very small - (1 - 2 MB).

Comment: @userDSSR As far as I can read from your question, then you do not want to make intermediary jsons. The read/writte is worse than having a middle class (Like "Spartak Singh") wrotte in his answer, as you can have significant changes later on in your project, without worrying on the limitations of JSONs. Also, the smaller and more readable the code, the better. Maintenance is a priority.

Answer (score 1):

If your code has a particular need, it is better to isolate and internalize that need rather than polluting the class space.

You can do that by keeping a `Map<ClassA, ClassA>` inside the class that wants to keep track of temporary values. The keys of the map are the objects that get processed. The values of the map hold the temporary values.

When you no longer need the temporary values, call `map.remove(obj)`.

Comment: Thanks @Bohemian.  Good suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

I don't quite understand what you're trying to do but I hope this helps:

```
abstract class A{
    int a;
    int b;
    public void update(){
        changeA();
        changeB();
    }
    protected abstract void changeA();
    protected abstract void changeB();
}
class B extends A{
    int c,d;
    protected void changeA(){
        a += c;
    }
    protected void changeB(){
        b += d;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply and the example.  This will also be a big help and will have run a few tests to try it out.  Thanks.